# How can a C program on Mac OS/X learn that the user has double-clicked to open an associated file?

Tags: c, macos, file-association

Normally in Obj C, NSApplicationDelegate handles this. But how would I do it in C?
I guess what I am asking it, how did Mac programs do this before OS/X came along?
Thanks.

Comment: I should point out that NSApplicationDelegate merely *handles* it, it doesn't actually detect it. (It receives an event)

Comment: Is there a reason your app has to be pure C? If you've already got a standard CFRunLoop, initializing the ObjC runtime is pretty trivial. And if not (unless you've got a Carbon event loop instead), there most likely is no easy way to do what you want, period.

Answer (score 5):

In Mac OS 9, applications opened documents at launch (or later on) by registering for and receiving an `'odoc'` Apple Event at startup. This is nontrivial to do in C, and I'd strongly recommend you not attempt it. In particular, note that this is unlikely to work properly unless your application has a Carbon event loop.

Before even that, there was also a mechanism whereby files for an application to open at launch were specified in a block of memory at the top of the stack. This mechanism no longer exists on OS X, so it's irrelevant today.

Comment: As abarnet notes in the above, it really depends on what kind of event loop (if any) your application has.